# New column is coming as index instead of comma separated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `2 Dataframes (eg df1, df2)`. I am trying to append/add a column from `df2` to `df1`. I am able to add but only issue is that new column which I have appended is coming with index. I want to have comma separated instead of having with index . New to python not sure how to do it ?

`Note: Order and columns are different for the dataframes df1 and df2`

Any help would be appreciated.

Sample code

```
df1.at[index, 'NewColumn'] = df2['file_name']
```

Output CSV:

[Output CSV For your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9byT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to python but I was working with CSV file just another day, so for you to remove the index you have to use `strip()` python function and delimiter for comma  separated CSV file. for more info check out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5uM4VKywbA)

Comment: This may resolve the issue. However, please consider adding some more details like sample code to make answer more useful.